# Actualizar tabla html

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo este `Ajax` el cual me hace una actualizacion, y leugo le paso para que me elimine el contenido que esta checkd,

Mi error es que también tengo que eliminar de la tabla general la cual no se como quitarla.

Este es el `ajax`

```
$(function() {

    $('#btn-analisisInt').click(function() {
    var lineasPreajuste= [];
        $('#contTabla2 input:checked').closest("tr").each(function() {


           // var linea= {
                articulo = $(this).find(".articulo").text();
                ubicacion = $(this).find(".ubicacion").text();
                ovs = $(this).find(".ovs").text();
                ufisica = $(this).find(".ufisica").text();
                existencia = +$(this).find(".existencia").text();
                //existencia =  existencia.toFixed(3);
                cantidadC = +$(this).find(".cantidadC").text();
                //cantidadC = cantidadC.toFixed(3);
                resultDif =  +$(this).find(".resultDif").text();
                //resultDif = resultDif.toFixed(3);
                promedio =  +$(this).find(".promedio").text();
            //}

            //lineasPreajuste.push(linea);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/Preajustes',
                method: 'post',
                data:{
                    articulo: articulo,
                    ubicacion: ubicacion,
                    ovs: ovs,
                    ufisica: ufisica,
                    existencia: existencia,
                    cantidadC: cantidadC,
                    resultDif: resultDif,
                    promedio: promedio
                },
                success: function(response){
                    console.log(response);
                    $('.case:checked').eq(0).parent().parent().remove()
                    swal({
                        title: "Se traslado correctamente el articulo a preajuste.",
                        text: "",
                        timer: 2000,
                        showConfirmButton: false
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    });
});
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se muestra en la imagen solo soy capaz de borrar lo que hay en el modal pero no soy capaz de borrarla de la tabla general. Todo pasa cuando le doy al boton PreAjustar.

Comment: Espero haber entendido bien tu planteamieno; si en la modal realizas acciones que se guardan como cambios aceptardos te sugiero realizar una actualización de la tabla (volver a cargar los datos) de la tabla general.

Comment: Y como puedo actualizar la tablar

Comment: En este momento el código ya está construido para hacer esta acción de eliminar un elemento de la tabla, o es eso que lo estás tratando de hacer?

Comment: Si la llenas por Ajax, invocando de nuevo el Ajax; pero si la llenas al momento de cargar la página haciendo que luego de *aceptar los cambios* recargar de nuevo la página.